Number relations in a number table
I found this puzzle in a school study group. Choices are 9, 10,11, 12, 13.
$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline 22& 22 & 23 & 24 \\ \hline 22 & 32& 41& 52\\ \hline 23 & 41 & 50 & 61\\ \hline x & 17 & 26& 37 \\ \hline \end{array} $$
I have tried so many operations on these numbers with many various arrangements.
I think the 4th row is a result of first three rows.

Where did you get this puzzle from?

No its not a homework or contest question. Its just a practice question, but it is really hard and I have been stuck with it for a week.

The answer is

 9

Logic

 Column wise the number in the bottom row is the result of sum of red x orange + sum of yellow - green

 So for the first column you get: (2+2)x2+(2+2-3)=9


And with that I am off to bed.

Unbelievable solution.
